# Use pre-existing Action Bar styles to style the toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm in the process of migrating an app from AppCompat-v20 to AppCompat-v21.  As part of that process, I'm trying to move away from the Action Bar, and replace it with a `Toolbar` so we can take advantage of all the new Material design goodness.

Previously, we had defined all of the information about the AB's displayOptions in a style, and then we set that style as the `actionBarStyle` in the Activity's theme.  However, now that I'm extending Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar those properties aren't respected anymore, which makes sense, because my theme extends `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.  At the same time, I would still like to have those `displayOptions` be applied in the same places they were before (i.e. I'd like to be able to specify whether I want to use a logo or show home as part of the theme).

I know I can probably do this by putting `displayOptions` onto the theme and parsing them myself, but I'm wondering if there's any support within AppCompat for `Toolbar`s to handle this logic automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `Toolbar` what you have to remember is that it is basically just a view group so you can customize it a lot easier and more so than you could with the `ActionBar`. That being said, you can use styles to alter the appearance of the `Toolbar` however there are methods for settings things like title/logo/navigation.

Here's an example of styling your `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

If you are using `ActionBarActivities` and `Fragments` then you can call the following to let Android know to use your `Toolbar` as the supportActionBar. This means that all of your calls to `getSupportActionBar()` will still be valid.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The new Material Design guidelines have started to move away from using Logos but if you insist on settings one you can like so:

```
toolbar.setLogo();
```

Your question was slightly vague so for more info checkout [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) by Chris Banes and Nick Butcher and then [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).

Comment: I'm fine setting a `Toolbar` as my supportActionBar. What I want is the ability to use my themes.xml and styles.xml to specify whether I want to display the logo/up button.  With the Action Bar I could do this by specifying `displayOptions` in my style.  It appears that the Toolbar doesn't expose a `setDisplayOptions`, so I'm also guessing that it isn't worthwhile to assign them to the Toolbar itself.

Comment: That's correct. Toolbar has no `setDisplayOptions` so if you want to implement these features you could optionally parse these yourself then setup the Toolbar via some of the methods I outlined